# Metadata API readMetadata truncates base64 values?

Tags: metadata-api

I'm trying to use readMetadata in the metadata API to download various things about an org. This works great for most everything but base64 values are always truncated..

Here's my test aura component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
        fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat 
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</aura:component>
```

Here's a request I send to soapui to test:

```
<soapenv:Envelope ...>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <met:SessionHeader>
         <met:sessionId>yadda.yadda</met:sessionId>
      </met:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <met:readMetadata>
            <met:type>AuraDefinitionBundle</met:type>
            <met:fullNames>MetadataApiTest</met:fullNames>
        </met:readMetadata>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope ...>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <readMetadataResponse>
         <result>
            <records xsi:type="AuraDefinitionBundle">
               <fullName>MetadataApiTest</fullName>
               <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
               <auraDefinitions>
                  <auraDefinition>
                     <defType>1(db=1,api=CONTROLLER)</defType>
                     <source>KHsKCW15QWN0aW9uIDogZnVuY3Rpb24oY29tcG9uZW50LCBldmVudCwgaGVscGVyKSAKICAgIHsKICAgICAgICB2YXIgeCA9IDE7CiAgICAgICAgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyAKICAgICAgICB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IAogICAgICAgIHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgCiAg</source>
                  </auraDefinition>
                  <auraDefinition>
                     <defType>2(db=2,api=COMPONENT)</defType>
                     <source>PGF1cmE6Y29tcG9uZW50IGltcGxlbWVudHM9ImZsZXhpcGFnZTphdmFpbGFibGVGb3JSZWNvcmRIb21lLGZvcmNlOmhhc1JlY29yZElkIiBhY2Nlc3M9Imdsb2JhbCIgPgoJPHA+TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgCiAgICAgICAgZWxpdCwgc2VkIGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIAogICAgICAgIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWduYSBhbGlxdWEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQg</source>
                  </auraDefinition>
               </auraDefinitions>
               <controllerContent>KHsKCW15QWN0aW9uIDogZnVuY3Rpb24oY29tcG9uZW50LCBldmVudCwgaGVscGVyKSAKICAgIHsKICAgICAgICB2YXIgeCA9IDE7CiAgICAgICAgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyAKICAgICAgICB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IAogICAgICAgIHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgeCsrOyB4Kys7IHgrKzsgCiAg</controllerContent>
               <description>here is a description.</description>
               <markup>PGF1cmE6Y29tcG9uZW50IGltcGxlbWVudHM9ImZsZXhpcGFnZTphdmFpbGFibGVGb3JSZWNvcmRIb21lLGZvcmNlOmhhc1JlY29yZElkIiBhY2Nlc3M9Imdsb2JhbCIgPgoJPHA+TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0gZG9sb3Igc2l0IGFtZXQsIGNvbnNlY3RldHVyIGFkaXBpc2NpbmcgCiAgICAgICAgZWxpdCwgc2VkIGRvIGVpdXNtb2QgdGVtcG9yIGluY2lkaWR1bnQgdXQgbGFib3JlIAogICAgICAgIGV0IGRvbG9yZSBtYWduYSBhbGlxdWEuIFV0IGVuaW0gYWQg</markup>
               <type>Component</type>
            </records>
         </result>
      </readMetadataResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I decode the response, I get only this much:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
        et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
```

All base64 values that I see get truncated at about this same size (or maybe this exact size - I have not checked).

I see types like profiles having no problem returning 500kb responses, so I don't think it's a size issue.

I'm not using a wsdl - this is building the requests and parsing the responses 'by hand', because I'm a glutton for punishment or something. Everything else works and the base64 responses are short but look fine otherwise.

Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the entire sequence of setting up your test and then performing your test.

Comment: @identigral, I included the sample aura component and the soap ui request that i used to reproduce this problem. If you can't plug these straight into salesforce and soap ui, please let me know.

Comment: How did you create your Aura component?

Comment: i've seen this issue on components created with dev console and welkin - any method will work fine.. the component works as-expected and my question is about using the metadata api to retrieve it.

Comment: ....if you try to create this component via Dev Console, you'd get an error message.

Comment: open the dev console; do File->New->Lightning Component; use the name: MetadataApiTest, click Component over on the right or do ctrl-shift-1 then copy/paste the content from the first code block. Do File->Save.   Does this not work for you?

Comment: No - value too large.